# How to initialize correctly an array with Array.CreateInstance() method

Tags: c#

I am working with a project and I got stucked, I want to create an array of a class, this class contains two `int` fields, I want to create an instance with `Array.CreateInstance()`, this method creates correctly an array with the correct length but instead of giving access to the int variables, the array is initialize as an array of `null`.

This is a simulation, the name of the class `ProcessFaults` is read during runtime with the reflection.

```
public class ProcessFaults
{

    public int _class;

    public int _group;

    public ProcessFaults()
    {

    }
}

class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object activatorTest = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Container));

       
        FieldInfo arrayFieldInfoInsideClass = Type.GetType("Testing_Reflection.Container").GetField("_dataProcessFaults", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        Type arrayTypeInsideClass = arrayFieldInfoInsideClass.FieldType;

        FieldInfo elementClassInsideArray = arrayTypeInsideClass.GetElementType().GetField("_class", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);


        Array a = Array.CreateInstance(arrayTypeInsideClass, 10);
}
}
```

that Produces following Output:

[image]

- Is there any form to initialize correctly the array?
- Is there any form to write directly to the variable _class and _group?

Regards!

Comment: Do `var arr = (ProcessTypes[])a;` then initialise `arr[]` in a loop as you would a normal array.

Comment: the array is length 10 of the class ProcessFaults @TheGeneral.

Comment: @MatthewWatson the explicit cast would work, i think i did not mention that in run time i do not know the explicit name of the class ProcessFaults, ProcessFaults is read with reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of an array are always null when it is first instantiated if those types are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

```
var x =  new ProcessFaults[10];
Console.WriteLine(x[0] == null); // writes "True"
```

In your case, you simply iterate over the array and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to instantiate a new instance and  `SetValue` to set it to the `Array`

```
for(var i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
    a.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(arrayTypeInsideClass),i);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/65Iji8